# hide a row of table filled dynamically with a button click php-jquery

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic-tables

good evening, I have dynamically filled my table from the database. at the end of each row I have a button.
my idea is : when i clicked the button the row is hidden. I succes to recuperate the id of each row but jquery code does not work and my console doesn't return any error. i don't know where the problem is? or even if the process  is correct.

also,at the latest i hope to replace the button with a checkbox but i don't know how to apply my idea with a checkbox

```
   <table name="table" class="table" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <?php
        include 'controller.php';
        $controller1 = new Controller();
        $res = $controller1->array();

        while ($donne = $res->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <tr id="<?php $donne['id'] ?>">
                <td> <?php echo $donne['operateur'] ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $donne['machine'] ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $donne['declaration'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post' style="display: inline;">
                        <input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value="<?php echo $donne['id']; ?>" />
                        <input  type='submit' name='validate' id='validate' value='validate' />

                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

and this is my jQuery code

```
 if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
        ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#validate").click(function () {
                    var i = $("#id").val();
                    var i = i.toString()
                    $("#" + i).hide();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <?php
    }
```

Comment: If this is repeating, you will have a an HTML issue as you will have multiple `#id` elements.

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery to hide the preferred row bi either id or class after loading dynamically.
this is an example:

// Denotes total number of rows.
var rowIdx = 0;

// jQuery button click event to add a row.
$('#addBtn').on('click', function () {

```
// Adding a row inside the tbody.
$('#tbody').append(`<tr id="R${++rowIdx}">
      <td class="row-index text-center">
            <p>Row ${rowIdx}</p></td>
       <td class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-danger remove" 
            type="button">Remove</button>
        </td>
       </tr>`);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".validate").click(function() {
    var i = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
    $("#" + i).hide();
    var url = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>";
    $.post(url, {
      id: i,
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="table" class="table" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row-1">
      <td>
        operateur 1
      </td>
      <td>
        machine 1
      </td>
      <td>
        declaration 1
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="validate">Validate</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-2">
      <td>
        operateur 2
      </td>
      <td>
        machine 2
      </td>
      <td>
        declaration 2
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="validate">Validate</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-3">
      <td>
        operateur 3
      </td>
      <td>
        machine 3
      </td>
      <td>
        declaration 3
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="validate">Validate</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will apply the callback to each Button. When the button is clicked,the Row is hidden and the ID is posted to your PHP Script.

Comment: i replace my script with this and change the class of my button to validate but still not working . i can share the whole code here maybe uu can find mistake and thank uu so much Mr @twisty also i think that because uu give for each row an id ="row-1 2...." but in my case table is dynamic so ...

Comment: @phrozeng all HTML ID's must be unique. If you want to use PasteBin or something like that to share your current Code, I can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

i find my mistake .i have set the same id for each button,that's wrong,so i use class instead of id also in this way i could recuperate the id simply and apply .hide()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".validate").click(function () {
        var num = $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
        alert(num);
       
    });
</script>
```

i delete the form also because there is no need anmore